# When using ExecuteAndWait, how to avoid prepare() and validate() methods on each refresh?

Tags: struts2

Through a recent debugging session I realized that when refreshing a "wait" page during an ExecuteAndWait process, it calls the action's prepare() and validate() methods each time. For some reason I thought Struts would immediately identify the "waiting" Action, and if it wasn't finished, it would immediately return a WAIT result with the running Action at the top of the stack.  I now realize since the ExecuteAndWait interceptor is at the end of the interceptor stack - so it obviously doesn't send the WAIT result until all interceptors have been executed.

That said, in some of my long running actions, the prepare() method hits the database for some rather resource heavy database queries. So if I have an ExecuteAndWait page showing the progress status of an Action (refreshing every 2 seconds in my case), this seems incredibly inefficient.  Is there a way to avoid this?  Am I setting up my Action logic flow incorrectly?

A sample of one of my Action setups in struts.xml:

```xml
    <action name="ContactDelete" class="com.afs.web.struts.action.contact.ContactDeleteAction">
      <interceptor-ref name="myParamsPrepareParamsStack" />
      <result>/struts/contact/contactDelete_modal.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">/struts/common/error/error_modal.jsp</result>
      <result name="login">/struts/common/login/login_modal.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="ContactDelete_delete" class="com.afs.web.struts.action.contact.ContactDeleteAction" method="delete">
      <interceptor-ref name="myDefaultStack"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="openSessionExecuteAndWaitInterceptor" >
        <param name="delay">0</param>
      </interceptor-ref>

      <result name="input">/struts/contact/contactDelete_modal.jsp</result>
      <result name="wait">/struts/common/progressMonitorWait_modal.jsp</result>
      <result>/struts/common/progressMonitorSuccess_modal.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">/struts/common/error/error_modal.jsp</result>
      <result name="login">/struts/common/login/login_modal.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: `ContactDeleteAction ` is the action w/ the heavy `prepare` functionality? If the `delete` method doesn't require the `prepare` functionality, use the `excludeMethods` on the `prepare` interceptor so it doesn't run on the `delete` method. Conversely, you could also move the heavy prepare work to a `prepareWhatever` method so it's targeted only at the method that needs it. It's not clear what exactly has the heavy prepare work, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton All this makes sense, but my confusion lies in needing to run the `prepare()` & `validate()` methods on the *first* time the `ContactDelete_delete` action is called.  I do need to verify that delete parameters have been entered correctly.  Then the subsequent calls to `ContactDelete_delete` (as part of the "are you done yet" ExecuteAndWait logic) shouldn't be calling `prepare()` and `validate()`. I tried to set "run_once" boolean flags, but this obviously fails since each subsequent call to the action are a new thread.  Does this makes sense?

Comment: @DaveNewton And the calls in the `prepare()` method aren't "heavy" per se, but they do hit the database with at least 3-4 queries on existing users, category lists, etc.  I just think it's inefficient to be preparing all these lists and form elements for the `contactDelete_modal.jsp` input page many times while waiting for the Action to finish.

Comment: @DaveNewton And for what it's worth - I miss you commenting on the Struts User Mailing list.  You were always the smartest guy in the room!

Comment: _lol_ Hardly ;) You could always try a thread local, with the caveat that you'd have to re-initialize it on first entry. Alternatively, you could have the "wait" part actually be a different method (or possibly action) and avoid the problem altogether, depending on how the method really works.